# I'm trying to develop an android and I need some advices

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, foreground-service

I'm trying to develop an app that retrieves from firebase the state of electric doors in some different cities and if a door error exists in any city, the app would automatically call or send SMS to the manager of that specific city based on the phone number saved in the db and this app should work in the background as well, I think I must start a foreground service but I wasn't so sure because I'm a beginner, could anyone advice me please.
here's my db structure [db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaDgc.png).

Comment: You also can use https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

Comment: Are only allowed to send SMS, or a notification can also help?

Comment: Yes i'm only allowed to sens SMS or to make phone call without user interaction.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.